# How to re-call constructor of an inititialized 3D vector

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, element

I think the problem is linked to this constructor:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> itemMatrix;
ItemConstruct(int numOfZ, int numOfY, int numOfX)
:itemMatrix(numOfZ, vector<vector<int>>(numOfY, vector<int>(numOfX, 1))){}
```

and when I try to call in:

```
int main (int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    int a1; int b1; int c1;
    int a2; int b2; int c2;
    Space i1;
    Item i2;
    ItemConstruct i3;
    cin>>a1>>b1>>c1>>a2>>b2>>c2;
    i1.setSize(a1, b1, c1);
    i2.setSize(a2, b2, c2);
    cout<<"answer: "<<i3.getA();
    cin.ignore(10, '\n');
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

I got an error like:

> No matching constructor for initialization of 'ItemConstruct'

```
class ItemConstruct
{
private:
    int numOfX;
    int numOfY;
    int numOfZ;
    int A;
public:
    void reqOfItem (Space spc, Item item)
    {
        numOfX = item.getX()/spc.getX();
        numOfY = item.getY()/spc.getY();
        numOfZ = item.getZ()/spc.getZ();
    }
    int getNumOfZ() {return numOfZ;} int getNumOfY() {return numOfY;} int getNumOfX() {return numOfX;}
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> itemMatrix;
    ItemConstruct(int numOfZ, int numOfY, int numOfX)
    :itemMatrix(numOfZ, vector<vector<int>>(numOfY, vector<int>(numOfX, 1))){}
    void Matrix (int Z, int Y, int X)
    {
        for(int z=1; z<=Z; z++)
        {
            for(int y=1; y<=Y; y++)
            {
                for(int x=1; x<=X; x++)
                {
                    itemMatrix[z][y][x]=15;
                }
            }
        }
        A=itemMatrix[2][2][2];
    }
    int getA()
    {
        return A;
    }

};
```

In Addition I am not sure about how to change an element of 3D vector. I tried changing by "for" loop as you see above. You can ignore the "A" value. I just want to make sure how the method works. I am very new to C++ language. Please help me to correct my script in a proper way.

Thanks.

Comment: you are trying to call a default constructor (callable without arguments) but your `ItemConstruct` has none. Either provide a default constructor or provide the parameters that are needed for construction

Comment: Don't construct the object until you get the values to construct it with.  Unlike C you do not need to declare everything upfront.  Standard practice is to declare things as close to the point of use as possible so it is easier to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
ItemConstruct i3;
```

you are calling the default constructor (a ctr callable without parameters), but your class has none. You could turn your constructor into a default constructor by providing default values for the parameters:

```
ItemConstruct(int numOfZ = 0, int numOfY = 0, int numOfX = 0)
```

However, the better approach is to make sure you have all that is needed to construct an object before calling the constructor (after constructing the object, it should be in a valid state and this is not always possible with a default constructor. The parameters might be essential to put the object in a meaningful state) :

```
int a,b,c;
cin>>a>>b>>c;
ItemConstruct i3(a,b,c);
```